# Use variable expressions in test.each Jest

Tags: jestjs

Below is my code snippet:

```
describe('Upper Describe,()=>{
  let value;
  beforeEach(()=>{
    value=require('testModule').value;
  });

  it.each([
    `${value}`,
  ])('test something',(value)=>{
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

Here the `value` comes to be `undefined`.

My guess is it is because as the describe blocks get loaded at the starting so are the values for `it.each`. Can anyone please help me with a workaround to get the variable values inside it.each array?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why don't you move the `require` out of the `describe`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing the value itself to `it.each` pass a function that returns the value.

This will delay evaluation of the value so `beforeEach` can modify what gets returned:

```js
describe('Upper Describe', () => {
  let value;
  beforeEach(() => {
    value = require('testModule').value;
  });

  it.each([
    () => `${value}`,  // pass a function that returns the value
  ])('test something', (func) => {
    console.log(func());  // SUCCESS: prints value export from testModule
  });
});
```

Comment: I just saw [your post on github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6413#issuecomment-424651322) and it helped me understand the issue better, I've updated my answer with a workaround.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much :) It would be very helpful if you can also tell me how to include `value` in it statement. Like I want my it statement to be more understandable, so if `value = abc`, I want my it statement's description to be `test something for abc`. Can you help me in achieving this too?

Comment: You can ["generate unique test titles by positionally injecting parameters with printf formatting"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtable-name-fn-timeout), but you wouldn't be able to inject `value` since [the title gets formatted before `beforeEach` runs](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/728ca114c06daa1c980d2d114142c8d6d3dd0dfb/packages/jest-each/src/bind.js#L57).  Looks like the best you could do would be something like `'test something %#'` to add the array index to the test title.